# Issue with integrating Cygnus and NGSI DynamoDB Sink

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

I have followed the tutorial in https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/historic-context-flume/index.html

Git repo: https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Historic-Context-Flume.git

I'm able to persist data from Cygnus to MongoDB, PostgreSQL DB and MySQL DB. I need to persist data from Cygnus to DynamoDB. Can anyone help me in providing the right docker configuration for Orion Context Broker, Cygnus (Common and NGSI) and NGSI DynamoDB Sink and also a sample context data format and a corresponding subscription POST request format? So that I can see a DynamoDB table automatically created and the context data changes reflect in the DynamoDB table after deploying their docker images and posting context data to the Broker.

Cygnus logs:

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "loggers": "[{"name":"org.apache.zookeeper","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.apache.kafka","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.mortbay","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.apache.hadoop","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.apache.http","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.apache.flume.lifecycle","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.mongodb","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.I0Itec","level":"WARN"},{"name":"com.amazonaws","level":"WARN"},{"name":"org.jboss","level":"WARN"}]"
}
```

Cygnus-DB stats:

```
{
    "success": "true",
    "stats": {
        "sources": [
            {
                "name": "http-source",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:52.712Z",
                "num_received_events": 992,
                "num_processed_events": 991
            }
        ],
        "channels": [
            {
                "name": "orion-channel",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:42:05.493Z",
                "num_events": 0,
                "num_puts_ok": 991,
                "num_puts_failed": 0,
                "num_takes_ok": 991,
                "num_takes_failed": 1498
            },
            {
                "name": "mongo-channel",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:53.532Z",
                "num_events": 983,
                "num_puts_ok": 991,
                "num_puts_failed": 0,
                "num_takes_ok": 8,
                "num_takes_failed": 95
            },
            {
                "name": "postgresql-channel",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:53.533Z",
                "num_events": 172,
                "num_puts_ok": 991,
                "num_puts_failed": 0,
                "num_takes_ok": 819,
                "num_takes_failed": 97
            },
            {
                "name": "mysql-channel",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:53.573Z",
                "num_events": 0,
                "num_puts_ok": 991,
                "num_puts_failed": 0,
                "num_takes_ok": 991,
                "num_takes_failed": 1497
            },
            {
                "name": "dynamo-channel",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "unknown",
                "num_events": -1,
                "num_puts_ok": -1,
                "num_puts_failed": -1,
                "num_takes_ok": -1,
                "num_takes_failed": -1
            }
        ],
        "sinks": [
            {
                "name": "dynamo-sink",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:52.779Z",
                "num_processed_events": 991,
                "num_persisted_events": 991
            },
            {
                "name": "mongo-sink",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:52.799Z",
                "num_processed_events": 8,
                "num_persisted_events": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "postgresql-sink",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:52.825Z",
                "num_processed_events": 819,
                "num_persisted_events": 0
            },
            {
                "name": "mysql-sink",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:52.841Z",
                "num_processed_events": 991,
                "num_persisted_events": 991
            },
            {
                "name": "orion-sink",
                "status": "START",
                "setup_time": "2020-03-19T06:41:52.867Z",
                "num_processed_events": 991,
                "num_persisted_events": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```